# Prevent NULLs on select average values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent NULLs on return from a `select` and do not return anything (0 rows) for that query where I provide incorrect `state` value as

```
select avg(lat) as lat, avg(lon) as lon from locations where city = "New York" and state = "NC"
```

I have tried something like

```
select case when avg(lat) != NULL then avg(lat) end as lat, case when avg(lon) != NULL then avg(lon) end as lon from locations where city ="New York" and state="NC"
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: What's wrong with adding `AND lat IS NOT NULL AND lon is NOT NULL` filter?

Comment: @raina77ow I did that at the beginning and still was showing NULLs

Comment: Please remember: NULL is neither equal nor not equal to anything - not even to itself. So you need to check `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  This, however, would not suppress empty lines - just allowed you to control the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function without`group by` always returns a row. So you need to add some `group by` (for example, `group by city`) or `having avg(lat) is not null` to prevent output on an empty input dataset (filtered).

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select *
> from (values
>   row(1, 'NY'),
>   row(3, 'NY'),
>   row(null, 'LA')
> ) as t(lat, state)
> ```

> ```
> select state, avg(lat) as alat
> from t
> group by state
> ```
>
> ```
> state |   alat
> :---- | -----:
> NY    | 2.0000
> LA    |   null
> ```

> ```
> /*No input rows - empty*/
> select avg(lat)
> from t
> where state = 'AR'
> group by state
> ```
>
> ```
> | avg(lat) |
> | -------: |
> ```

> ```
> /*There's input row,
> but the avg is empty - empty output*/
> select avg(lat)
> from t
> where state = 'LA'
> group by state
> ```
>
> ```
> | avg(lat) |
> | -------: |
> |     null |
> ```

> ```
> /*There's a row and avg is empty,
> but we filter it out with having*/
> select avg(lat)
> from t
> where state = 'LA'
> group by state
> having avg(lat) is not null
> ```
>
> ```
> | avg(lat) |
> | -------: |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2afd898ba5914d0a86d37804c09a665e)*

Comment: `group by` works like a charm. Did not looked for such of simple solution. I have tried `having` too but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Comment: @JackTheKnife `group by` will handle empty input, but `having` can also handle empty column. I'll post the code

Comment: @JackTheKnife I've added possible cases which you can adapt to your needs)